# How to create a x64 (instead of AnyCPU) build of .Net based Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: azure

I'm using Azure 2.7.

I created a C# cloud service that only contains a single worker role. After it's done, the solution contains

- A ccproj
- A csproj

Both are using the setting of AnyCPU.

I then added the PropertyGroup "Debug|x64" and "Release|x64" into both projects. Also changed the default to x64 for both. As a result, an x64 build.

However, whenever I select "publish" on the "ccproj", I notice that it always builds AnyCPU instead of x64. I cannot find how to force it to build x64 for packaging and deployment.

I then edited both proj file again, and removed the PropertyGroup for "Debug|AnyCPU" and "Release|AnyCPU". After I did this, and when I tried to build x64 again, I got error as:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(723,5):
>   error : The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'AzureWorkerRoleExample.ccproj'.  Please check to make sure that you
>   have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for
>   this project.  Configuration='Release'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  This error
>   may also appear if some other project is trying to follow a
>   project-to-project reference to this project, this project has been
>   unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the referencing
>   project does not build using the same or an equivalent Configuration
>   or Platform.

I could not figure out how to work around this error.

Any idea on how to force VS to make a x64 build of cloud service and deploy it?

One workaround I found is that: keep AnyCPU property groups, but also put

`<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>`

in the group. Thus the AnyCPU assembly are actually targetting to x64. But this sounds hacky.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I changed 
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'"> to 
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'"> but it feels wrong.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: no, I did not find a solution.

Comment: What .Net framework is this project?